# How to incorporate thresholds for limit check with a provided static value to compare against?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

here is the instance:

```
Column 1     Column 2    Column 3
2.99         4            Price OK            
1.99         4            Price below limit             
12.99                                  
5.99         6            Price OK
1.99         6            Price below limit
8.99         6            Price OK
```

So for Power BI context Column 2 is a custom column from power query, the goal is to set a threshold value for column 2 pack size, in this instance pack size of 4 needs to check for minimum price of $2.99 (higher is ok), below the price should be below limit, in instance of column 2 blanks (result should also be blank). In the instance of size 6 the minimum price to check for is 5.99.

Is there a decent way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this in two steps. First, create a column `MinPrice` that defines your minimum prices.

```
if [Column 2] = 4 then 2.99
else if [Column 2] = 6 then 5.99
else null
```

Then create a column that compares the actual and the minimal

```
if [Column 1] = null or [Column 2] = null then null
else if [Column 1] < [MinPrice] then "Price below limit"
else "Price OK"
```

If you have a bunch of unique values in `Column 2` that you need to create rules for, then create a reference table that you can merge onto your original table and expand the `MinPrice` column instead of the first step stated above.

```
Column2  MinPrice
-----------------
4        2.99
6        5.99
8        7.99
...
```

Comment: this does not work in the manner needed, all values result as null. The thresholds are not apparent for the (2) price limits

Comment: How are the limits set is that's not what `Column 2` is?

Comment: Column 2 is the descriptor for the qty pack of a product package, so imagine bundles of produce (4 ears of corn, 6 pk beer, etc)

Comment: Where are the limits defined though? I can't write a custom column that checks against the limit when no such information is provided.

Comment: it can't be placed in the formula? Like an if that compares with a static value that if the value in column is less than then ""?? The limits are not placed but currently intuitive values, Should a reference table be made? Or can a provided value be compared agianst?

Comment: the rules are as such: If Column 2 is (4) then Column 1 should not be less than 2.99 and if Column 2 is (6) Column (1) should not be less than 5.99 if column is blank then null??

Comment: Sure, you can write rules like that but it's going to be clunky if you have more than a couple. If it's just 4 and 6, that's fine but if you have a bunch, then you'll want a reference table to work with.

Comment: just the two in this scenario